# Is there a way to dynamically refer to a module and its functions in rust?

Tags: rust

As I am completing Advent of Code 2021, I have a `main.rs` file that looks like this:

```
// # Day 1
    if day1::is_complete() && print_complete || !day1::is_complete() {
        day1::part1();
        day1::part2();
    } else {
        println!("✅ Day 1 finished!")
    }

    // # Day 2
    if day2::is_complete() && print_complete || !day2::is_complete() {
        day2::part1();
        day2::part2();
    } else {
        println!("✅ Day 2 finished!")
    }

...
```

This continues for all 25 days.

Every module has a function called `part1` and `part2`.

Is there a way to do something like this for a more concise file like the python `eval`?

```
for day in 1..=25 {
   let mod_name = convert_to_mod_name(day);
   if mod_name::is_complete() && print_complete || !mod_name::is_complete() {
        mod_name::part1();
        mod_name::part2();
    } else {
        println!("✅ Day {day} finished!", day);
    }
```

Comment: Modules are not first-class objects in Rust. Your best bet would be to make each day a struct, all of which implement a common trait specifying how to "evaluate" it.

Comment: You can do something like that with macros, but not that exactly without invoking `rustc`.

Comment: I was wondering, any progress on that? I have a similar problem?

Comment: No, no progress on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to do something like this for a more concise file like the python `eval`?

No. Python is a dynamic language. Rust is a statically compiled language.

The closest thing would be to load a dynamic link library. Rust doesn't have a stable ABI except for a small subset meant for FFI. That is inherently unsafe.

TL;DR: It's not worth for something like advent of code.